# SCDF on k8s: Configure Dataflow Server to start Task Container with volume

Tags: kubernetes, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to find a way to configure the Spring Cloud Dataflow Server, which I'm deploying to kubernetes, so that it mounts a volume into the pods it creates whenever I am starting a task.

I got an application called `my-batch-app` and a task called `my-batch-task`

I'm deploying the SCDF server like so:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: spring-cloud-dataflow-deployment
  namespace: demo
spec:
  revisionHistoryLimit: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: spring-cloud-dataflow
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: spring-cloud-dataflow
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: spring-cloud-dataflow
          image: <my_custom_image>
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: "5m"
              memory: "480M"
            limits:
              cpu: "4"
              memory: "2G"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          startupProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /scdf/dashboard
              port: 8080
            failureThreshold: 30
            periodSeconds: 10
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /scdf/dashboard
              port: 8080
            failureThreshold: 2
            periodSeconds: 10
          args:
            - --spring.cloud.deployer.my-batch-app.kubernetes.volumes=[{name:'my-batch-volume',persistentVolumeClaim:{claimName:'my-batch-pvc'}}]
            - --spring.cloud.deployer.my-batch-app.kubernetes.volumeMounts=[{name:'my-batch-volume',mountPath:'/tmp'}]
            - --spring.cloud.dataflow.features.streams-enabled=false
            - --spring.cloud.dataflow.features.schedules-enabled=false
            - --spring.cloud.dataflow.features.tasks-enabled=true
            - --spring.cloud.dataflow.task.platform.kubernetes.accounts.default.limits.memory=1024Mi
            - --spring.cloud.dataflow.task.platform.kubernetes.accounts.default.imagePullSecret=harbor-secret
            - --spring.cloud.dataflow.task.platform.kubernetes.accounts.default.imagePullPolicy=always
            - --spring.sql.init.mode=always
            - --spring.sql.init.data-locations=classpath*:/org/springframework/cloud/dataflow/server/db/migration/h2/V1__INITIAL_SETUP.sql
            - --spring.sql.init.continue-on-error=true
            - --spring.flyway.enabled=false
            - --server.port=8080
            - --server.servlet.context-path=/scdf
          env:
            - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL
              value: jdbc:h2:tcp://my-h2db-service:1521/scdf
            - name: KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: "metadata.namespace"
            - name: SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_ENABLED
              value: 'false'
            - name: SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_SERVER_URI
              value: 'http://scdf-service:8080'
            - name: SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_TASK_COMPOSED_TASK_RUNNER_URI
              value: 'docker://springcloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-composed-task-runner:2.6.3'
            - name: SPRING_CLOUD_KUBERNETES_CONFIG_ENABLE_API
              value: 'false'
            - name: SPRING_CLOUD_KUBERNETES_SECRETS_ENABLE_API
              value: 'false'
            - name: JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS
              value: '-Xmx1g'
      serviceAccountName: scdf-sa 
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: my-registry-secret
```

I thought with these args

```
- --spring.cloud.deployer.my-batch-app.kubernetes.volumes=[{name:'my-batch-volume',persistentVolumeClaim:{claimName:'my-batch-pvc'}}]
- --spring.cloud.deployer.my-batch-app.kubernetes.volumeMounts=[{name:'my-batch-volume',mountPath:'/tmp'}]
```

I could make it work, but maybe I am misunderstanding the documentation...
Whenever I'm starting the task it does not mount any volume into the pod. No error or anything is logged..

Any ideas?